# How to add multiple cross references to the multiple images added in a Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am able to add multiple images to a Word document using VBA and at the same time I am not able to add multiple cross references using VBA.

```
Sub checking()
    Dim strFolderPath
    strFolderPath = "C:\images"
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim objSelection
    Dim objShapes
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFolder

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:\myfile.docx")

    objWord.Visible = True

    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

    For Each Img In objFolder.Files

        ImgPath = Img.Path
        objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture (ImgPath            
        objSelection.insertbreak

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: For below code added images I need add the cross references for each images, if any body please suggest me.
Sub add_images()
FnInsertMultipleImages ("d:\Data\Images")
End Sub

Comment: function definitin is : Function FnInsertMultipleImages(strFolderPath)
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objSelection
Dim objShapes
Dim objFSO
Dim objFolder
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:\document.docx")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
For Each Img In objFolder.Files
ImgPath = Img.Path
   objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture (ImgPath)   
objSelection.insertbreak
  Next
End Function

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code there.

Comment: I provided an answer to the 3rd question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794824/10908769 and suggest to delete this question here.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to show you an example. You will have to amend it to suit your need. I am going to insert 2 images and create a `Cross Reference`. I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it.

**Logic:**

1. Add image
2. Add caption to image
3. Create the Cross Reference
4. Insert Page Break?
5. Repeat the above step

**Code:**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As InlineShape
    Dim n As Long

    '
    '~~> Insert Image 1
    '
    Set shp = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\ImageA.Png", _
                                                LinkToFile:=False, _
                                                SaveWithDocument:=True)

    '~~> Adding a caption
    n = 1
    CaptionLabels.Add Name:="MyImage" & n

    shp.Select
    Selection.InsertCaption Label:="MyImage" & n, TitleAutoText:="", Title:="", _
    Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=0

    Selection.InsertBreak


    '
    '~~> Insert Image 2
    '
    Set shp = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\ImageB.Png", _
                                                LinkToFile:=False, _
                                                SaveWithDocument:=True)

    '~~> Adding a caption
    n = n + 1
    CaptionLabels.Add Name:="MyImage" & n

    shp.Select
    Selection.InsertCaption Label:="MyImage" & n, TitleAutoText:="", Title:="", _
    Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=0

    Selection.InsertBreak

    '~~> Creating cross reference
    For n = 1 To 2
        Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="MyImage" & n, ReferenceKind:= _
        wdEntireCaption, ReferenceItem:=1, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
        IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks@Siddharth Rout for information but I am facing compilation error when I am including this steps in loop.

Comment: Set shp = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\ImageB.Png", _
                                                LinkToFile:=False, _
                                                SaveWithDocument:=True)

    '~~> Adding a caption
    n = n + 1
    CaptionLabels.Add Name:="MyImage" & n

    shp.Select
    Selection.InsertCaption Label:="MyImage" & n, TitleAutoText:="", Title:="", _
    Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, ExcludeLabel:=0

Comment: Compilation error is "user defined type of not defined " for InlineShape

Comment: Can you please implement in loop for adding and giving cross references for giving 15 different images present in a folder path. I tried but its shows some user defined types errors and others.. Thanks in advance@Sidharth Rout

Comment: I tried your code without modification also but I am getting user defined types errors.